# InfraRed receiver just works when measuring with multimeter

Tags: infrared

My air conditioner stopped receiving remote control commands.
Because it is very old, there are no spares.

The receiver board is very simple: 1 infrared (TSOP), 1 aluminum capacitor, some resistors and LEDs, and one 10K temperature probe. I started by replacing the IR LED but that didn't solve it.

Then I took the capacitor out and tested it with a Chinese tester and it seems ok. The resistors and LEDs look good and they work fine. I tested the 10K Temperature probe with a multimeter and it works ok.
To test if the 3 legs IR was receiving the remote commands, I put my multimeter on the ground and Vout of the IR LED. When I press on the remote control, the AC works fine.
Then I've realized that if I just touch with the multimeter -(negative) on the IR -(ground), everything works fine...can it be the capacitor?

Comment: Bad contacts. Resolder them.

Comment: Aluminium electrolytic capacitor, right? Those are notorious for dying after a long time... but, the capacitance would be much bigger than what you get from touching it with a multimeter probe.

Comment: Tried both suggestion without success.
Bought a new one :(